# How to prove the orthogonality of the Fourier basis from the dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

In order to prove the discrete fourier basis

$$ w^{(k)}_n = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}nk}$$
is orthogonal, the following was stated
[image: Fourier basis orthogonality proof]

But I am confused why it is 0 when $k \neq h$, How can the sum from $n=0$ to $ N-1 $ be $0$ ? I tried substituting values for $h-k$ by $2$, and $N$ by $5$, but in the summation there is always that $e^0$ which equals to 1 and no negative term to cancel it. Can someone clear this please?

Comment: Use the formula for a geometric sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n = \frac{1-\alpha^N}{1-\alpha}$, where $\alpha \stackrel{\rm def}{=} e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)}\neq 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the formula for a geometric sum $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha^n = \frac{1-\alpha^N}{1-\alpha}$, where $\alpha \stackrel{\rm def}{=} e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)}\neq 1$ (the last point because $h\neq k$).

It will be $0$ as $\alpha^N = e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}(h-k)\cdot N} = e^{-j 2\pi(h-k)} = e^0$ (recall that $h-k$ is an integer, and $x\mapsto e^{j2\pi x}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$).

Comment: Amazing, this thought never crossed my mind, BTW, I have this confusion, the series consists of positive number, but the sum is 0, how can sum of positive numbers be equal to 0? Is it something to do with the complex number being involved?

Comment: @TamimAddari  Yes: the sum is *not* a sum of positive numbers, it is a sum of *complex* numbers (all on the unit circle). (In case that is obscured by the use of $j$ instead of $i$: here, $j$ is the imaginary number usually denoted $i$, i.e. s.t. $j^2=-1$).

Comment: Too late into this post but I would like to add an extra line for future readers. The fact that the map $x\mapsto e^{2\pi j x}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ follows from Euler's formula: $e^{2\pi j x}=\cos(2\pi j x)+j\sin(2\pi j x)=1$.

Comment: Note that $\alpha$ Is not 0. The sum is 0.

Comment: @VitaliPom errr... yes? What are you making this comment in reference to? Nowhere was claimed that $\alpha$ is zero.

Comment: Oh, sorry hi, no it was for those who read the answer. I needed it for my self and due to “it will be 0” I thought for a while it refers to the alpha. The answer is okay, it wasn’t meant for you :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

if $h=k $, the sum is

$e^0+e^0+...e^0=1+1+...1=N $

if $h\ne h $, it is a geometric sum like

$$1+r+r^2+r^3+...r^{N-1}=\frac {1-r^N}{1-r }$$

with $r^N=1$.